# regular expression match no word character an white spaces

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm no good at at regular expression but here is my problem!
I need a regular expression to match  no word characters and white spaces but to escape characters like Ö,ä,ü,Ü,Äö .
I use PHP as server side scripting.

examlpe: `!@#!@$%>< #$$ #$@^%`  is a god match
         `!@##$%$#%# @$#@! !@#!@#ÖÄü`  is a bad match it has ÖÄü

I tried something like this

```
'/[.,;:@\-_()\!"\$%&\/=\?\*\`\~\^\\\|\'\+#<>{}\[\](\s)]/'
```

but '\s' is not matching white space's ????

If someone could correct this exression in order to alsow match white spaces it would be great.

```
'/[.,;:@\-_()\!"\$%&\/=\?\*\`\~\^\\\|\'\+#<>{}\[\]]/'
```

Any help is appreciated !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[utf-8 character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
/\p{L}/u
```

Comment: What have you done with it? This isn't finished code, this is to get you on your way.... The expression would probably be `/^\PL*$/u`', assuming you are using utf-8. Also, we don't know what you mean with _'to escape characters like Ö,ä...'_, escaping how and what for?